# I want to use variable check globally

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, geolocation

I want to use check variable globally. Because I want to include this file in another file and want to apply condition on the variable in which location is saved. But i am not able to use it globally. Kindly help me

```
    <script language="javascript">
    var check= "initial";
    function fun() {

    function displayLocation(latitude, longitude) {
    var request = new XMLHttpRequest();

    var method = 'GET';
    var url = 'http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json?latlng=' +   latitude + ',' + longitude + '&sensor=true';
    var async = true;

    request.open(method, url, async);
    request.onreadystatechange = function () {

        if (request.readyState == 4 && request.status == 200) {
            var data = JSON.parse(request.responseText);
            var address = data.results[1];
          check = address.formatted_address;
           alert(check);

        }
    };
    request.send();
};

var successCallback = function (position) {
    var x = position.coords.latitude;
    var y = position.coords.longitude;
    displayLocation(x, y);
};

var errorCallback = function (error) {
    var errorMessage = 'Unknown error';
    switch (error.code) {
        case 1:
            errorMessage = 'Permission denied';
            break;
        case 2:
            errorMessage = 'Position unavailable';
            break;
        case 3:
            errorMessage = 'Timeout';
            break;
    }
    alert(errorMessage);
};

var options = {
    enableHighAccuracy: true,
    timeout: 1000,
    maximumAge: 0
};

   navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(successCallback, errorCallback,      options);
   }
   fun();
   document.write(check);
  </script>
```

Comment: have you tried assigning it to window.check?

Comment: Yes i tried it but it didn't work

Comment: Can you please amend this code so that the last command of document.write may work.

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/08e8vmu9/

Comment: Its still giving value as initial.....But its not giving location

Comment: Please help me. I don't no what I have to do here. I have tried many things but i am not able to do it in the right way.

Comment: Your function @ line 12 is not getting called: https://jsfiddle.net/08e8vmu9/5/

Comment: Can you please amend this code? Its very important for me to resolve this issue please help me....

Comment: could put it into local storage or cookie.  Also isn't this just the same question you asked yesterday?

Comment: Hello Pete! It was my question i asked yesterday but i resolved that issue. can you please amend this code or provide any solution in the code please.?

Comment: Have a look at these: https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/API/Window/localStorage or https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/cookie very simple to use and can be accessed from other files / pages within your website

Comment: Thanks a lot. I got the solution